# use crystal reports in c# windows application

Tags: c#

I want to use crystal reports with c# windows application.In the crystal reprt i want to display data from text fields as well as datagridview.how to do it? can a report be binded to 2 tables?

Comment: Read this: [C# Crystal Reports String parameter](http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-string-parameter.htm) and this: [C# Crystal Reports from multiple tables](http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-multiple-tables.htm).

Comment: You could try something like these: http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Database/Generating-a-Multiple-Table-Crystal-Report-using-VS-2005/ http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/556_Creating_Crystal_Report_with_Multiple_Tables_in_ASP_NET.aspx http://www.emoreau.com/Entries/Articles/2006/09/Feeding-Crystal-Reports-from-your-application.aspx First two use Report Wizard but you can always look at generated report/dataset to understand how it is done.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new dataset from solution explorer to your project and add all the columns which includes the fields as well as datagridview, after adding all the rows point out the Dataset added to the Database Fields of the crystal report, see the below image [image: Adding Dataset to the Crystal Report]

Comment: the field values are not correctly displaying in the report. th report is not being displayed correctly.

Comment: Is it showing any exception to you? or do one thing right click on the report and select Design -> Printer Setup -> go to Size tab and change the size type there. Ensure under Name tab it should Document Writer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a DataSet and after that, you can add that DataSet to CrystalReport. 
The DataSet is fill in code behind when you are going to display the Report.

Here is an example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XrtzOKMJJIw